# How can I get Lightroom to be mathematically accurate when cropping to an aspect ratio?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

I've been using Lightroom to crop pictures to be square.  I'm doing this in the obvious way: in "Develop", click the Crop overlay, lock the padlock, and set the aspect ratio to "1x1".

This works, in that the resulting pictures do indeed "look square".  However, when I actually checked the dimensions of one of the pictures I exported, its exact pixel dimensions were 1679x1676.

Is "looks square" the best that Lightroom can do?  Or is there some way I can get the width and height to be exactly the same number of pixels?

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed from version 5.3 onward.

[You can download the latest Windows version here.](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=113&platform=Windows)

[You can download the latest Mac version here.](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=113&platform=Mac)

Comment: Do you have a link to a changelog for 5.3? It would be good to have an official statement that the bug has been fixed.

Comment: [Here is the changelog](http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2013/12/lightroom-5-3-now-available.html). However, it doesn't mention this bug...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using version 5.5 (mac).